# How to simplify / combine function equtions containing `if`?

Tags: functions

I have two eqution (blue / green), composed them using a simple `if` (black).

[image]

Blue: `(2x)^2 / 2`

Green: `0.5 + (1 - (2(1-x))^2) / 2`

Black: `(x < 0.5) ? (2x)^2 / 2 : 0.5 + (1 - (2(1-x))^2) / 2`

See it in action on Fooplot: http://fooplot.com/plot/7knnh3zxis

---

Question is **how can I simplify / extract the `if` statement?**

Seemingly this is a single eqution offset by `0.5, 0.5` from the origin. Can someone shed a light on how to simplify this? I have some other similar equtions I am to simplify.

I'm not a math ninja, so explain with care if you can. :)
Sorry if this is a noob question here at `math.stackexchange.com`, this is the first time I ask here.

---

UPDATE: I expressed as a single function, than it turned out that this all above can be simplified to a surprisingly simple function, like:
`-(4(x-0.5)abs((x-0.5))-4(x-0.5)-1)/2`

See http://fooplot.com/plot/t5msqna67s

Comment: Feel free to suggest better wording for question title.

Comment: There is not a unique way to simplify a function. For most purpouses the expression you have is the best way to express the function. Why you need a simplification? What's your goal?

Comment: Performance optimization, readability.

Comment: Hmm, actually every combined function will provide less performance, as I wondering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you with extracting mean to replace the "if" with some function then you could use the following function:

$\displaystyle t(x)=\frac{x+|x|}{2\cdot x}$ which is equal to
$ \;t(x)=\!\!
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
1 \quad\text{if } x>0\\ 
0 \quad\text{if } x<0
\end{array}
\right. 
$

In your example $f(x)=\text{blue}(x)\cdot t(x-0.5)+\text{green}(x)\cdot t(0.5-x)$.

Comment: Yap, simply "weight" the two eqution actually. I think this is actually the answer, but it is seemingly less performant.

Comment: @Geri: In a computer program it is less time efficient. And also, $t$ is not defined for $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write the whole function you have defined as a polynomial (sum of multiples of $x^n$). Your function is differentiable everywhere and *piecewise* a polynomial, but that doesn't mean that the function *as a whole* is a polynomial. To see this, note that your function's second derivative is discontinuous.

Although it's kind of cheating, you could write it as:

$$f(x):=\frac{2x^2}{2}+ U\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \left[\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1 - (2(1-x))^2}{2} - \frac{2x^2}{2}\right]$$

with 'U' being the 'unit step': $U(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 & x<0 \\ 1 & x \geq 0\end{array}\right.$

Note that some polynomials of degree 3 will have a similar shape to your function, but they will go off to infinity faster on their tail ends.

Comment: Aha, the second derivative is the key I was grasping for. Good call :)

Comment: Yap, I saw `x^3` functions, like `0.5 + ((-x+ 0.5)^3 + 2x) - 1` http://fooplot.com/plot/srw8xwhbdj

Comment: I just could not provide exactly the same...